# Method-level execution time metrics in Golang?

Tags: go

I am quite new to Go and I was wondering if there are any nice (like AOP in Java) ways to gather method-level execution time metrics in Go?

It would be best if such code would not be placed inside regular business logic code.

I don't want to profile an app. I mean real production ready metrics that could be exported to Graphite etc. so I could monitor response time histograms and such.

Comment: you mean beyond the built in profiler?

Comment: http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: Yes. So that it could be run on production and provide business metrics that could be exported to let's say: Graphite. I have seen a few "metrics" projects in Go, but they all require you to mix business logic with metering logic and this sucks (from my pov).

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite source code using the go parser and add the instructions. This is how `godebug` and the coverage tool work: https://github.com/mailgun/godebug.

Obviously that would be a lot of work, but I think your methodology is flawed anyway. Measuring everything means your program will spend far more time measuring than actually doing work. This is why profiling only samples.

It sounds like perhaps you're working on an HTTP project? You could easily instrument your code by wrapping all your `http.Handler`s or using a framework like [Negroni](https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni). Here's an [example](https://github.com/thoas/stats) of someone doing something similar. Go also has the [expvar](https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/) package which is sometimes useful for counters and the like.

Also worth considering is using a statsd client (which can get your data into Graphite). Here's one package which can do that: [godspeed](https://github.com/PagerDuty/godspeed)*. Calls are pretty easy:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/PagerDuty/godspeed"
    "github.com/codegangsta/negroni"
)

func statsdMiddleware(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc) {
    start := time.Now()
    next(w, r)
    elapsed := float64(time.Now().Sub(start)) / float64(time.Millisecond)

    g, err := godspeed.NewDefault()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer g.Conn.Close()

    g.Histogram("http.response.time_ms", elapsed, []string{"path:" + r.URL.Path})
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the home page!")
    })

    n := negroni.Classic()
    n.Use(negroni.HandlerFunc(statsdMiddleware))
    n.UseHandler(mux)
    n.Run(":3000")
}
```

This approach works for standard TCP servers as well. For pipelines reading / writing queues I usually measure how fast I'm reading in data and writing it out the other end and then use back-pressure gauges for the intermediate steps. (which helps me find out which step is causing the problem)

*Disclaimer: I work at DataDog*

Comment: Thanks for your reply and hints. I have no idea where did you read that I want to measure everything :) I just want to be able, in a declarative way, to define functions that should be measured (not only HTTP requests but also my own requests to external systems). What I don't like in the code you have pasted is that performance logic is interleaved with business logic but I suppose that is all that Golang has for the time being. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, the Go approach isn't perfect. But AOP has its downsides too.